# Swiping on a slide does not update the pagination active state on iOS Devices

Tags: android, ios, swiper.js

We have a slider from http://idangero.us/swiper with the following basic settings:
pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                },

Swiping on a slide does not update the pagination active state. Emulating touch on Chrome works but real devices or emulators for iOS show the bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="scroll-wrap swiper-container">
                        <div class="scroll-container swiper-wrapper" id="scroll-5">
                            {% for offer in sections['salebc'].offers %}
                            <div class="scroll-item swiper-slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rentTcModal">
                                <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/thumbs/') }}{{ offer.picture }}" alt="">
                                <div class="scroll-content">
                                    <h5>{{ offer.subtitle }}<br>
                                        <strong>{{ offer.title }}</strong></h5>
                                    <p>{{ offer.info }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="scroll-info">
                                    <p class="mb-0 pb-0"><span>Адрес:</span> {{ offer.adres }}</p>
                                    <p class="my-0"><span>Площадь:</span> {{ offer.square }} кв.м.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-pagination d-block d-md-none"></div>
                    </div>





let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remember about such Swiper.js param as `nested: true`. https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters

It might resolve your problem